# Read lines from a text file, reverse and save in a new text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

So far I have this code:

```
 f = open("text.txt", "rb")
 s = f.read()
 f.close()
 f = open("newtext.txt", "wb")
 f.write(s[::-1])
 f.close()
```

The text in the original file is:

```
This is Line 1
This is Line 2
This is Line 3
This is Line 4
```

And when it reverses it and saves it the new file looks like this:

```
 4 eniL si sihT 3 eniL si sihT 2 eniL si sihT 1 eniL si sihT
```

When I want it to look like this:

```
 This is line 4
 This is line 3
 This is line 2
 This is line 1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: If you are using Python 2.7, you do not have to close the file manually, use the `with` keyword:

    with open("text.txt", "rb") as if:
        lines = f.readlines()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f = open("text.txt", "rb")
s = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open("newtext.txt", "wb")
s.reverse()
for item in s:
  print>>f, item
f.close()
```

Answer (score 14):

You can do something like:

```
with open('test.txt') as f,  open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(reversed(f.readlines()))
```

Comment: This is beautiful, readable, pythonic code! Your answer deserves more upvotes.

Comment: To keep a header as the first line, add `fout.writelines(f.readline())` as for loop first line

Answer (score 4):

`read()` returns the whole file in a single string. That's why when you reverse it, it reverses the lines themselves too, not just their order. You want to reverse only the order of lines, you need to use `readlines()` to get a list of them (as a first approximation, it is equivalent to `s = f.read().split('\n')`):

```
s = f.readlines()
...
f.writelines(s[::-1])
# or f.writelines(reversed(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `file.read()` returns a string of the whole file, not the lines.

And since `s` is a string of the whole file, you're reversing the letters, not the lines!

First, you'll have to split it to lines:

```
s = f.read()
lines = s.split('\n')
```

Or:

```
lines = f.readlines()
```

And your method, it is already correct:

```
f.write(lines[::-1])
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of steps here. First we want to get all the lines from the first file, and then we want to write them in reversed order to the new file. The code for doing this is as follows

```
lines = []
with open('text.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('newtext.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in reversed(lines):
        f.write(line)
```

Firstly, we initialize a variable to hold our lines. Then we read all the lines from the 'test.txt' file. 
Secondly, we open our output file. Here we loop through the lines in reversed order, writing them to the output file as we go.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this if your OS uses `\n` to break lines

```
f = open("text.txt", "rb")
 s = f.read()
 f.close()
 f = open("newtext.txt", "wb")
 f.write(reversed(s.split("\n")).join("\n"))
 f.close()
```

Main thing here is `reversed(s.split("\n")).join("\n")`.

It does the following:

1. Split your string by line breaks - `\n`,
2. resulting an `array`
3. reverses the array
4. merges the array back with linebreaks `\n` to a `string`

Here the states:

1. string: `line1 \n line2 \n line3`
2. array: `["line1", "line2", "line3"]`
3. array: `["line3", "line2", "line1"]`
4. string: `line3 \n line2 \n line1 \n`

Answer (score 0):

A sample using list so it will be much easier:
I'm sure there answer that are more elegant but this way is clear to understand.

```
f = open(r"c:\test.txt", "rb")
s = f.read()
f.close()

rowList = []
for value in s:
    rowList.append(value + "\n")
rowList.reverse()


f = open(r"c:\test.txt", "wb")

for value in rowList:
    f.write(value)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to work line by line.

```
f = open("text.txt", "rb")
s = f.read()
f.close()
f = open("newtext.txt", "wb")
lines = s.split('\n')
f.write('\n'.join(lines[::-1]))
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, one problem though, the last two lines in the original always end up on the same line in the new file. So like "This is line 4.This is line 3." Any ideas why this is?

Comment: This is because you have different line endings then \n. This is unix standard. If you are using notepad like application to edit file this could happen. If you convert \r char to \n your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

If your input file is too big to fit in memory, here is an efficient way to reverse it:

1. Split input file into partial files (still in original order).
2. Read each partial file from last to first, reverse it and append to output file.

Implementation:

```
import os
from itertools import islice

input_path = "mylog.txt"
output_path = input_path + ".rev"

with open(input_path) as fi:
    for i, sli in enumerate(iter(lambda: list(islice(fi, 100000)), []), 1):
        with open(f"{output_path}.{i:05}", "w") as fo:
            fo.writelines(sli)

with open(output_path, "w") as fo:
    for file_index in range(i, 0, -1):
        path = f"{output_path}.{file_index:05}"
        with open(path) as fi:
            lines = fi.readlines()
        os.remove(path)
        for line in reversed(lines):
            fo.write(line)
```