# Can I save Python data in reverse order?

Tags: python

Using the basic functions 
f = open('test.txt', 'a')

saving data like this:
0
title(0)
main text(0)

1
title(1)
main text(1)

2
title(2)
main text(2)

.
.
.

but i want data sequence in reverse order like:

5
title(5)
main text(5)

.
. (skip 4,3,2)
.

1
title(1)
main text(1)

0
title(0)
main text(0)

How do I modify this function[f = open('test.txt', 'a')]?

Comment: The `open()` function is unrelated to the order of the data that will be written. You will  have to sort the data yourself before writing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read lines from a text file, reverse and save in a new text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19753814/read-lines-from-a-text-file-reverse-and-save-in-a-new-text-file)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Put the data into a pandas data frame then use:

```
df[::-1]
```

in order to reverse the order.